# Simple 2D 'Space Invaders' Clone In Silverlight

Tags: c#, vb.net, silverlight

I want to make a simple 2d game in Silverlight, but it seems like things have changed since the last time I tried to make a game using mode 13h graphics.  Can someone give me a run-down of how you'd go about it.

I just mean at a high-level, focusing on the silverlight-specific aspects; not general game design.

A fictional example might be:
'The main game loop shouldn't be a loop, use a DispatchTimer instead.  Use a Canvas as the main drawing object; but realize that we don't bother drawing individual pixels - all of your in-game objects should be represented by controls.  Be sure to set the 'UseHardwareFlag' to true'.  Etc, etc...

Comment: The more specific problem I'm having is that the background 'stars' appear to flicker/look choppy.  I'm using a dispatchTimer with a 5ms delay, a full screen canvas, and each 'star' is a Line object with a given x1,x2,y1,y2.  The stars move down the screen giving the appearance of movement; but it's not as smooth as I think it should be.  Maybe I should be using something other approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stick to the mode 13 way of programming have a look at the [WriteableBitmap](http://10rem.net/blog/2009/03/18/silverlight-3-%E2%80%93-the-bitmap-api---writeablebitmap).

[Some very nice demos here](http://blogs.cynergysystems.com/2009/08/31/advanced-render-techniques-with-writeablebitmaps/)

I succeeded in porting Wolf3D (2 and a half D) to Silverlight this way.
[I used the CompositionTarget.Rendering event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748838.aspx)

**EDIT**

[I also found this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/SilverlightGame07292008174708PM/SilverlightGame.aspx), it is less mode 13 and more in line with your example.

Comment: I added yet another example, more in line with your question

Comment: And where's this Silverlight Wolf3D port?

Comment: On my machine. I can't distribute it as it contains content with copyright. Sorry. In the meantime have a look at this: http://www.innoveware.com/ql3/QuakeLight.html